# Watermark Problem with Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-3

In my model I have

```
[Display(Prompt="Author First Name",Name="First Name")]
[StringLength(100,ErrorMessage="First Name may not be longer than 100 characters")]
public string AuthFirstName { get; set; }
```

I have a String.cshtml file that is

```
@Html.TextBox("",ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class="text-box single-line", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

In firefox and chrome when my form is displayed it correctly shows the watermark everytime. 
For some reason I cannot get them to show in Internet Explorer and unfortunatly most of my user base will be using this browser. I did install chrome frame and with that installed I get the watermark in IE but this may not be the most ideal solution for my many non technical users.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placeholders are only planned to be supported in IE10.
See http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

What you can do is to detect browser native support for placeholders using JavaScript, and if there is no support, fallback to a JavaScript implementation.

Here's an example using Modernizr for support detection and a jQuery plugin for the placeholder implementation: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/HTML5izerPlaceholder